# How to write unit test in nestjs and typeorm without connecting to db

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am not sure how to implement unit test in nestjs and typeorm without connecting to db. I have tried a number of technic but non seem to work.

My module looks something like this.

```
import { HttpModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import moment from 'moment';

import config from '@app/config'
import { OrdersService } from './services/order.service'
import { FraudOrderChecksService } from './services/fraud-order-checks.service'
import { FraudOrderChecksController } from './controllers/fraud-order-checks.controller'
import { HealthcheckController } from './controllers/healthcheck.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { ormconfig } from './entities/ormconfig'


@Module({
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        HttpModule,
        LoggerModule,
        ConfigModule.forRoot(config),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig.luminskin as any),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(ormconfig.meridian as any),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([...ormconfig.luminskin.entities], 'luminskin'),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([...ormconfig.meridian.entities], 'meridian'),
        ...
    ],
    controllers: [
        MyController,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I import the root module in my test

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [InternalModule]
    }).compile();
    ...
  });
```

When I try to run my unit test I get

```
[Nest] 93196   - 06/04/2021, 17:43:50   [ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database (mydb). Retrying (1)...
AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "connectionname", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.
```

How do I decouple the connection from the root module, so it is only ran when needed. Actually cleaner technic will also be accepted.

Comment: there's a big thread for this question here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1267

Comment: @MicaelLevi Seen it but I am not sure how this will be implemented in nestjs. Any pointers will help.

Comment: I'd say that instead of import the entire `InternalModule`, just load the providers or services that you need for the test suite. Or, since `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` will try to connect to your db, you should mock `'@nestjs/typeorm'` to make it return your test double instead when importing the `TypeOrmModule` class. I didn't tried this yet tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to unit test a module, you want to unit test a modules individual components in isolation.

Although you *can* create a TestModule and simply import your module as you have done above, I would only consider doing that when the module contained a single component (even then I wouldn't as I don't think its very good practice).

The more components you bring into your test:

- The more moving parts you need to manage
- The more you have to mock
- The less portability you have with the unit and its test
- The more aspirin you ingest trying resolve self induced headaches that occur every time you modify its parent module

Nests TestingModule enables you to "rig" up an independent module with the bare minimum needed to **test your component in isolation**. It simplifies your test setups and mock creation/management.

Always try to look at unit testing as a stand alone, independent processes. Limit the scope and dependencies wherever possible to make testing as effective and easy as possible.

Here is an example of the approach I take for unit testing a service where I mock out its dependencies:

```
// app.service.spec.ts

describe('Testing app.service', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let service: AppService;

  // mock out providers the service depends on
  const mockProviders = [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: {
        get: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('Mock!'),
      },
    },
  ];

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // build up testing module
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [...mockProviders, AppService],
    })
      .compile()
      .catch((err) => {
        // Helps catch ninja like errors from compilation
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
      });

    service = module.get<AppService>(AppService);
  });

  it('Should return: Hello Mock!', async () => {
    const response = service.getHello();
    expect(response).toEqual('Hello Mock');
  });
});
```

I try to keep all business logic (wherever possible) in services, leavingcontrollers light and generally reserved for e2e and/or integration testing.

This isn't the only (and maybe not even "the best") approach, but it helps me to keep my tests and services more focused.

Comment: Humor the original premise of the question for a second. If one has to test the module itself (say for example, to run the whole app as a test to generate an OpenAPI spec, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64935977)) how would one go about mocking out the `TypeOrmModule.forRoot...` call?